# how to free handles in java

Tags: java

In my program code there are many threads. When my program starts and end then the number of handles are not freed. When the program starts for the second time, the number of handles increased. This happens each time. Also the number of threads for the program increased. Can anybody tell me how to free the handles? Because there is the problem of handle leak in my program.

Comment: what do you mean by "handles"? is your program terminating gracefully? what objects are you using? usually setting an object to `null` will make it a candidate for garbage collection, but it would help if you posted some relevant code...

Comment: since code is very large , it is a complete project for purge so i think it would not possible for me to post. So as you said to set them null will make them candidate for garbage collection but there are a very large number of handles , so I am using System.gc() , will it not work

Comment: Garbage collection has very little to do with filehandle leaks - all GC will do is delete any objects from memory which aren't referenced any more.  This is inherently internal to Java and won't affect external resources (with the caveat that the object may have finalizers that close resources but this is rare, and generally considered to be A Bad Idea anyway...).

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle, how do you know he's referencing file handles?

Comment: Based on the terminology, it's probably ^nix, where "Everything is a file".  It might not strictly be *file* handles, but the principles of how you deal with the problem in Java are basically identical for any kind of IO resource (even in Windows).

Comment: actually i am working in a multi-threaded environment. My project is for purge which run for nightly basys to delete all the unused thing from the database. so there are number of threads which is dynamic and can be increase or decrease.there are a connection pool in the program to connect from database which contains connections open with databse. also a list of connection which are in use. now my project terminate gracefully but handels must be freed as when the task is finished for one day . so as next day it start again then the number of handels should not be increase.

Answer (score 5):

You're not closing the streams that are using these handles.  Any time you use some sort of I/O resource, you need to ensure it's closed.  Classically this should be done in a `finally` block to ensure that it's called whatever happens, such as:

```
final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt");
try {
    // Do whatever you want with the stream:
    //   - read from it directly
    //   - call other methods etc.
    // Just make sure you're really finished with it
    // by the end of this try block!
}
finally {
    in.close();
}
```

The same applies to database connections, HTTP connections, various URL resources - pretty much anything with a `close()` method.

Looking at what type of handles these actually are (files/DB/network ports) and any details (such as filename, remote host etc.) will help you track down which parts of your program aren't closing their resources correctly.

---

It's a good idea to get the `try { ... } finally { foo.close(); }` idiom embedded into your programming muscle-memory, as you **always** want to be treating resources like this.  It's the only reliable way to prevent leaks, and should be done when writing the code the first time rather than when chasing down bugs later.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Andrzej has said :
Check if your custom objects are overriding the finalize () method. If finalize method is throwing exception then that object will never be garbage collected.

Check the usage of static collections are really required, generally static collections are long lived.

May be you can try using soft refrences and weak refrences so that when next time garbage collections happen , the objects referred to by them may become eligible for garbage collection.

Again to note : system.gc () is a request and not a forceful command so it may not yield the exact expected number.